# Using RfcommSocket with BLE without pairing?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to both java and android and I am currently working on a simple data logging app for information sent via bluetooth. I have recently switched to using an HM-10 (CC41) BLE module from classic bluetooth. Since I don't know anything about using Gatt characteristics to create a connection and receive data, I would like to continue using socket communication. My phone S7 edge is not able to pair to the BLE device though so it's not an option for me to create a bond programatically before starting the RfcommSocket. Is there any way to continue using socket communication without pairing? Finally, I already have the MAC address of my BLE module so I would rather not be scanning. Here is my relevant code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {

```
private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
private InputStream inputStream;
private OutputStream outputStream;
private Thread thread;
private TextView Status;
private TextView Connection;
private BluetoothSocket socket = null;
public boolean threadStatusInitial; //changed the status global variables to public static
public boolean threadStatus;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    threadStatusInitial=true;
    threadStatus=true;

    Status=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.StatusID);

    Connection=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ConnectionStatus);

    adapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(adapter==null){

        Toast.makeText(this,"bluetooth is unavailable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        finish();
        return;
    }
    thread=new Thread(this);

}

public void connect(View view){
    BluetoothDevice device=adapter.getRemoteDevice("3C:A3:08:94:C3:11");


            try {
                socket=device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());

                socket.connect();

                Connection.setText("Connected");

                inputStream=socket.getInputStream();

                outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();


                if (threadStatusInitial){
                   thread.start();
                   threadStatusInitial=false; //this ensures that the thread.start() method will only be called during the initial connection
               }
               threadStatus=true; 





            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Can't Connect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }






}
```

The thread related global variables have to do with maintaining the logging thread during disconnects and reconnects to the BLE module.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey how about accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

First of all Bluetooth low energy is not meant to use Sockets for connection and data transfer. The whole point of BLE is to keep power consumption as low as possible that cannot be achieved by sockets as they maintain the continue data transfer stream regardless we are sending any data or not.
You can get help from this link for android- HM10 communication.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/12/connect-hm-10-ble-module-to-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth classic and Bluetooth Low Energy, although related are different standards. For a classic connection you would use something like the code you have illustrated. But a BLE client is much different. Requires completely different client code. I think your device HM-10 (CC41) BLE module  likely only supports BLE. I believe your only choice is to migrate to BLE.